# Azure - How to download azure resource group automation script through powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure, resources

I want to download the automation script of a resource group in Azure through PowerShell. As of now I know, how to login to Azure through PowerShell and access resource group but I don't know how to access settings of a resource group.

Comment: Welcome. Rather than "I don't know how" it is encouraged to "I tried this, expected that and got something else" in a demonstrative manner that includes the code to support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cmdlet you are looking for is `Export-AzureRmResourceGroup`.

One tip, you can use `get-command` to look for "ideas". like so:

```
Get-Command -Module azurerm.resources
```

or

```
Get-Command -Module azurerm.resources -verb export
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/export-azurermresourcegroup?view=azurermps-5.2.0